# Javascript Web Firebase get token running local but not running in public IP

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new in Firebase, and I am trying to figure out how to make my simple web app get token.

Since this is just prototype, I have 3 files.

1: `init.js`

```js
// Initialize Firebase
const config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX"
}
var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
console.log(defaultApp.name);  

// Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');

}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});

// Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
// subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
if (currentToken) {
    console.log('token 1 : '+currentToken);
    var el = document.getElementById("firebaseToken").value = currentToken;
} else {
    console.log('token 2 : '+currentToken)
}
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
});

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log("Message received. ", payload);
});
```

2: `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <textarea id='firebaseToken'></textarea>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-functions.js"></script>

    <script src="init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

3: `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

const config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX"
}

var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
console.log(defaultApp.name);  

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/itwonders-web-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

The problem is when I publish my code on Windows hosting, my web app
prototype doesn't get the token (I host in *somee.com*). But it works fine in *000webhost.com* (Linux hosting), and also run with no problem in localhost.

The error says:

> code: "messaging/unsupported-browser"
>   message: "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."
>
> stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)

Do I have to configure something on Windows server? Open port or etc?

Here's the screenshots:

[image: Screenshot error when hosted in Somee.com (Windows based hosting)]
[image: Screenshot web work fine in 000webhost]

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the root cause.

the reason firebase not running on somee.com.
Because in somee.com i dont use ssl. but 000webhost got SSL. thats why firebase running on 000webhost.

because based on this :

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1220

firebase wont running on https not http.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHif9.png)